# How to format logs and add elapsed time with LoggingHandler in Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration DSL with Java 1.7 and AMQP, and I am trying to log my events with LoggingHandler through logback, this is a snippet of my configuration code.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow inboundFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundGateway(simpleMessageListenerContainer())
            .mappedReplyHeaders(AMQPConstants.AMQP_CUSTOM_HEADER_FIELD_NAME_MATCH_PATTERN)
            .mappedRequestHeaders(AMQPConstants.AMQP_CUSTOM_HEADER_FIELD_NAME_MATCH_PATTERN)
            .errorChannel(gatewayErrorChannel())
            .requestChannel(gatewayRequestChannel())
            .replyChannel(gatewayResponseChannel())
        )
        .transform(getCustomFromJsonTransformer())
        .route(new HeaderValueRouter(AMQPConstants.OPERATION_ROUTING_KEY))
        .get();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel gatewayRequestChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.publishSubscribe().get();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel gatewayResponseChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.publishSubscribe().get();
}

@Bean
public LoggingHandler getLoggingHandler(){
    LoggingHandler loggingHandler =  new LoggingHandler(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO.name());
    loggingHandler.setLoggerName("analytics");
    loggingHandler.setExpression("headers");
    return loggingHandler;
}

private IntegrationFlow fileLoggerOutboundFlowTemplate(MessageChannel fromMessageChannel) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(fromMessageChannel)
        .handle(getLoggingHandler())
        .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow requestFileLoggerOutboundFlow() {
    return fileLoggerOutboundFlowTemplate(gatewayRequestChannel());
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow responseFileLoggerOutboundFlow() {
    return fileLoggerOutboundFlowTemplate(gatewayResponseChannel());
}
```

Now, I have two main problems here:

1. This loggingHandler is logging headers from request and response to logback, an example for a response log entry with headers I currently have, look like this :

   ```
   {errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@ff940b1, replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@ff940b1, contentType=JSON, amqp_consumerQueue=clientAdapter, userId=12345678, monitoringId=34841e03-a7f8-4f0b-8860-2f94c94e2c7a, timestamp=1454460846221, id=799de4c1-6167-6f45-de4d-1964d357d2dc, adapterRoutingKey=clientRoutingKey, messageType=RESPONSE, operationRoutingKey=login, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-YMP8rrbTxLAXdYsFJ7HVjQ, result=OK, metaData={"clientVersion":"1.2.1","clientType":"WEB","ipAddress":"127.0.0.1"}}
   ```

So, the question here is, is there a way to format this output to kind of CSV format using an expression? This make me think that maybe this could be solved with a logback layout.

2. This log events happen in two different times, with request and response, is there a way to log elapsed time between request and response? I was using Splunk to process both log entries and calculate elapsed time but I would like to have this in one log line and avoid Splunk because license cost.

Thanks for your help.

UPDATE:

At the end, I used what Artem Bilan proposed with `enrichHeaders()`, I added timestamp in the request and when response is going to send back calculate elapsed time.

Also I have to say, that this requirement about logging in CSV format is more than just logging, so decided to handle this in a different way using AMQP to track every transaction and have it in the desired format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Not sure what you mean about "CSV format using an expression". But you really can use any bean from that expression and build any format from there. According your CSV requirements I can assume that you finally will aggregate all logs into one file. So, maybe something like `headers.values()`, would be enough for the start. But you should bear in mind that not all map instances will be sorted the same way.
2. The `LoggingHandler` isn't intended to do that. Its responsibility just log the message coming to is channel. That is a main message principle - *loose coupling*. There are a couple of techniques which can help you determine the proper solution.

2.1 Since you are going to to elapse the time between request and response (and looks like you already can do that with Splunk), so, you can *aggregate* them the similar way using `.aggregate()` from Spring Integration. And only after that send the single message with the desired time field to the logger.

2.2 Another way (and I found it as better one). Just calculate the request message before sending it to the process channel. E.g. `.enrichHeaders()` can help you with that. And use that header when the response is ready to return to calculate the elapsed time. And only from here send the single message to the logger.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have to say that after to see your response, I used `enrichHeaders()` to add timestamp to headers, and calculate elapsed time when the response is ready.